# quick way to split one line script into well formatted script

Tags: vim

source script as below.

```
qiniu(){    backup ;     cd  /tmp/back ;     for  srcName in `ls $dir` ; do  qshell fput helloworld  $srcName   $dir$srcName ;     done ;     if [ "$1" ==  "-s" ] ; then sudo shutdown -P ;     fi ; }
```

well formatted script.

```
qiniu(){    
    backup ;     
    cd  /tmp/back ;     
    for  srcName in `ls $dir` ;
        do  qshell fput helloworld  $srcName   $dir$srcName ;     
    done ;     
    if [ "$1" ==  "-s" ] ;
        then sudo shutdown -P ;     
    fi ;
}
```

Is there a quick way to split one line script  into well formatted script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split lines on certain syntax elements, and then let Vim's indenter reindent the file:

```
:setf sh | %substitute/\%([{;]\|\<do\>\|\<then\>\)\zs/\r/g | 1normal! =G
```

#### Result

```
qiniu(){
    backup ;
    cd  /tmp/back ;
    for  srcName in `ls $dir` ;
    do
        qshell fput helloworld  $srcName   $dir$srcName ;
    done ;
    if [ "$1" ==  "-s" ] ;
    then
        sudo shutdown -P ;
    fi ;
}
```